# Pattern condition involving multiple arguments to a function

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

I can define conditions on individual arguments to a function:

```
f[a_List/;condition(a),b_List/;condition(b)]:=(...)
```

I am wondering if there is a way of declaring something like this:

```
f[a_List,b_List/;condition(a,b)]:=(...)
```

so for instance, I might want to be sure that a and b are of the same size or that {a,b} follows a certain pattern for example.

I know I can leave the condition cases inside the body of the function but I am wondering if there is any way of avoiding that.

Comment: Note that `patt /; test` is a shorthand for `Condition[patt, test]`. You are writing `f[a_, Condition[b_, test[a,b]]]`, but there is no `a` in the pattern in the first argument of `Condition` in this case. Note also that function definitions in *Mathematica* are nothing but patterns, so it is harmless to put the entire left hand side in the first argument of `Condition`, then you will have access to all symbols in the second argument of `Condition`. This is what eldo does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`f[a_List,b_List/;condition(a,b)]:=(...)` is not possible

Instead write:

```
fun[a_List, b_List] /; Length@a == Length@b := 1
fun[a_List, b_List] := 2

fun[Range@3, Range@3]
```

> 1

```
fun[Range@3, Range@4]
```

> 2

Also possible:

```
fun[a_List, b_List] := 1 /; Length@a == Length@b
```